# Does stargate work with Materialized view?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, materialized-views, stargate-oss

I created a materialized view on Datastax cassandra. When I am using Stargate rest api to get the data from the view, it returns

```
{
    "description": "Resource not found: table 'view_user_by_status' not found",
    "code": 404
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time no. I've been meaning to log a Github issue on this, it should be a pretty simple change. I'll get an issue logged and update this answer with the link.

EDIT: Here's the [issue](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/issues/1324).

Comment: My team is thinking about stop using Stargate because of this issue. Please fix it asap :-)

Comment: FYI a PR is in the works https://github.com/stargate/stargate/pull/1349